# Improve PSTricks code for drawing of a football pitch

Tags: pstricks, code-review

Consider the following example.

**Code**

```
% pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

% Paremeters
\def\laengde{90 }
\def\bredde{45 }
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-4)(45,90)
\psset{unit=0.18cm,nrot=:U,dotsize=3pt 2}
 \pnodes{P}(0,0)(0,0)%
  (0,\laengde)%
  (!0 \laengde 2 div)%
  (!\bredde \laengde 2 div)%
  (!\bredde 2 div \laengde 2 div)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 16.5 7.32 2 div add add 16.5)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 16.5 7.32 2 div add add 0)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 16.5 7.32 2 div add sub 0)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 11)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 7.32 2 div 5.5 add sub 0)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 7.32 2 div 5.5 add sub 5.5)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 7.32 2 div 5.5 add add 0)%
  (!\bredde 7.32 sub 2 div 0)%
  (!\bredde 7.32 add 2 div 0)%
  (!\bredde 2 div \laengde 11 sub)
 % Outline and middle of the field.
 \pspolygon(P1)(P2)(\bredde,\laengde)(\bredde,0)
 \psline(P3)(P4)
 \pcline[offset=9pt]{|<->|}(P1)(P2)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize\SI{\laengde}{\m}}
 \pcline[offset=-80pt]{<->}(P3)(P4)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize\SI{\bredde}{\m}}
 \psdots(P5)(P9)(P15)
 \pscircle(P5){9.15}
 % Lower part of the field.
 \pcline[offset=9pt]{<->}(P7)(P6)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize\SI{16.5}{\m}}
 \pcline{<->}(!\bredde 2 div 0)(P9)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize\SI{11}{\m}}
 \psarc(P9){9.15}{37}{143}
 \pcline{<->}(P9)(!\bredde 2 div 9.15 2 div add 11 9.15 3 sqrt 2 div mul add)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize\SI{9.15}{\m}}
 \psline(P10)(P11)(!\bredde 2 div 7.32 2 div 5.5 add add 5.5)(P12)
 \psline(P8)(!\bredde 2 div 16.5 7.32 2 div add sub 16.5)(P6)(P7)
 \pcline[offset=-6pt]{<->}(P10)(P11)
 \ncput*{\tiny\SI{5.5}{\m}}
 \psline(P13)(!\bredde 7.32 sub 2 div -2)(!\bredde 7.32 add 2 div -2)(P14)
 \pcline[offset=-9pt]{|<->}(!\bredde 2 div 16.5 7.32 2 div add sub 0)(P13)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize\SI{16.5}{\m}}
 \pcline[offset=-16pt]{|<->|}(P13)(P14)
 \ncput*{\tiny\SI{7.32}{\m}}
 \pcline[offset=6pt]{|<->}(P14)(P12)
 \ncput*{\tiny\SI{5.5}{\m}}
 % Upper part of the field.
 \psline(!\bredde 2 div 16.5 7.32 2 div add sub \laengde)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 16.5 7.32 2 div add sub \laengde 16.5 sub)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 16.5 7.32 2 div add add \laengde 16.5 sub)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 16.5 7.32 2 div add add \laengde)
 \psarc(P15){9.15}{217}{323}
 \psline(!\bredde 2 div 7.32 2 div 5.5 add sub \laengde)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 7.32 2 div 5.5 add sub \laengde 5.5 sub)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 7.32 2 div 5.5 add add \laengde 5.5 sub)%
  (!\bredde 2 div 7.32 2 div 5.5 add add \laengde)
 \psline(!\bredde 7.32 sub 2 div \laengde)%
  (!\bredde 7.32 sub 2 div \laengde 2 add)%
  (!\bredde 7.32 add 2 div \laengde 2 add)%
  (!\bredde 7.32 add 2 div \laengde)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Question**

I have the desired output but the code is not very elegant; can anyone help me simplify if?

**Update 1**

So far I have the following:

```
% pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

% Paremeters
\def\laengde{90 }
\def\bredde{45 }
\psset{unit=0.18cm,dimen=middel}
\begin{pspicture}(-25,-50)(25,50)
 % Outline and middle of the field
 \psdot(0,0)
 \pscircle(0,0){9.15}
 \psline(!\bredde 2 div neg 0)(!\bredde 2 div 0)
 \psframe(!\bredde 2 div neg \laengde 2 div neg)(!\bredde 2 div \laengde 2 div)
 % Lower part of the field.
 \psframe(!20.16 neg \laengde 2 div neg)(!20.16 \laengde 2 div neg 16.5 add)
 \psframe(!9.16 neg \laengde 2 div neg)(!9.16 \laengde 2 div neg 5.5 add)
 \psframe(!3.66 neg \laengde 2 div neg)(!3.66 \laengde 2 div 1.5 add neg)
 \psdot(!0 \laengde 2 div neg 11 add)
 \psarc(!0 \laengde 2 div neg 11 add){9.15}{37}{143}
 % Upper part of the field.
 \psframe(!20.16 neg \laengde 2 div)(!20.16 \laengde 2 div 16.5 sub)
 \psframe(!9.16 neg \laengde 2 div)(!9.16 \laengde 2 div 5.5 sub)
 \psframe(!3.66 neg \laengde 2 div)(!3.66 \laengde 2 div 1.5 add)
 \psdot(!0 \laengde 2 div 11 sub)
 \psarc(!0 \laengde 2 div 11 sub){9.15}{217}{323}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Now, all the lengths are missing and the code can probably be made even 'simpler'.

**Update 2**

```
% pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

% Paremeters
\def\laengde{90 }
\def\bredde{45 }
\centering
\psset{
  unit=0.18cm,
  dimen=middel,
  nrot=:U,
  dotsize=3pt 2
}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(45,95)
 % Banens omrids og midterfelt.
 \psframe(0,0)(\bredde,\laengde)
 \psline(!0 \laengde 2 div)(!\bredde \laengde 2 div)
 \pcline[offset=9pt]{|<->|}(0,0)(0,\laengde)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize{\SI{\laengde}{\m}}}
 \pcline[offset=-80pt]{<->}(!0 \laengde 2 div)(!\bredde \laengde 2 div)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize{\SI{\bredde}{\m}}}
 \psdot(!\bredde 2 div \laengde 2 div)
 \pscircle(!\bredde 2 div \laengde 2 div){9.15}
 % Den nederste del af banen.
 \psframe(!\bredde 2 div 20.16 sub 0)(!\bredde 2 div 20.16 add 16.5)
 \psframe(!\bredde 2 div 9.16 sub 0)(!\bredde 2 div 9.16 add 5.5)
 \psframe(!\bredde 7.32 sub 2 div 0)(!\bredde 7.32 add 2 div 2 neg)
 \pcline[offset=9pt]{<->}(!\bredde 2 div 20.16 add 0)(!\bredde 2 div 20.16 add 16.5)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize{\SI{16.5}{\m}}}
 \pcline{<->}(!\bredde 2 div 0)(!\bredde 2 div 11)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize{\SI{11}{\m}}}
 \pcline{<->}(!\bredde 2 div 11)(!\bredde 2 div 4.575 add 11 9.15 3 sqrt 2 div mul add)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize{\SI{9.15}{\m}}}
 \pcline[offset=-6pt]{<->}(!\bredde 2 div 9.16 sub 0)(!\bredde 2 div 9.16 sub 5.5)
 \ncput*{\tiny{\SI{5.5}{\m}}}
 \pcline[offset=-9pt]{|<->}(!\bredde 2 div 20.16 sub 0)(!\bredde 7.32 sub 2 div 0)
 \ncput*{\scriptsize{\SI{16.5}{\m}}}
 \pcline[offset=-18pt]{|<->|}(!\bredde 7.32 sub 2 div 0)(!\bredde 7.32 add 2 div 0)
 \ncput*{\tiny{\SI{7.32}{\m}}}
 \pcline[offset=6pt]{|<->}(!\bredde 7.32 add 2 div 0)(!\bredde 2 div 9.16 add 0)
 \ncput*{\tiny{\SI{5.5}{\m}}}
 \psdot(!\bredde 2 div 11)
 \psarc(!\bredde 2 div 11){9.15}{37}{143}
 % Den øverste del af banen.
 \psframe(!\bredde 2 div 20.16 sub \laengde)(!\bredde 2 div 20.16 add \laengde 16.5 sub)
 \psframe(!\bredde 2 div 9.16 sub \laengde)(!\bredde 2 div 9.16 add \laengde 5.5 sub)
 \psframe(!\bredde 7.32 sub 2 div \laengde)(!\bredde 7.32 add 2 div \laengde 2 add)
 \psdot(!\bredde 2 div \laengde 11 sub)
 \psarc(!\bredde 2 div \laengde 11 sub){9.15}{217}{323}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I have switched back to letting `(0,0)` be the bottom left corner of the pitch instead of letting `(0,0)` be the middel. (I have just tried both; what is 'best'?) Furthermore, all the length are now on the figure.

**Update 3**

Here is the final version. (Thanks to Herbert!)

```
% pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\def\laengde{\Laengde 2 div }
\def\bredde{\Bredde 2 div }
\def\goalwidth{\Goalwidth 2 div }
\def\halffield{%
  \psline(!\goalwidth neg 0)(!\goalwidth neg 2)%
         (!\goalwidth 2)(!\goalwidth 0)
  \psline(!\goalwidth neg 5.5 sub 0)(!\goalwidth neg 5.5 sub -5.5)%
         (!\goalwidth 5.5 add -5.5)(!\goalwidth 5.5 add 0)
  \psline(!\goalwidth neg 16.5 sub 0)(!\goalwidth neg 16.5 sub -16.5)%
         (!\goalwidth 16.5 add -16.5)(!\goalwidth 16.5 add 0)%
 \rput(0,-11){\psdot(0,0)\psarcn(0,0){9.15}{-37}{-143}}
}
\def\Label#1{\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\scriptsize\SI{#1}{\m}}}

% Paremeters
\def\Laengde{90 }
\def\Bredde{45 }
\def\Goalwidth{7.32 }
\psset{
  unit=1.8mm,
  dimen=middel,
  nrot=:U,
  dotsize=3pt 2
}
\begin{pspicture}(-25,-50)(25,50)
  \psframe(!\bredde neg \laengde neg)(!\bredde \laengde)
  \psdot(0,0)\psline(!\bredde neg 0)(!\bredde 0)\pscircle(0,0){9.15}
  \rput(!0 \laengde){\halffield}
  \rput{180}(!0 \laengde neg){\halffield}
  \pcline[offset=9pt]{|<->|}(!\bredde neg \laengde neg)(!\bredde neg \laengde)
  \Label{\Laengde}
  \pcline{<->}(!\bredde neg \laengde 3 div neg)(!\bredde \laengde 3 div neg)
  \Label{\Bredde}
  \rput(!0 \laengde neg){%
    \pcline[offset=-7pt]{|<->}(!\goalwidth neg 16.5 sub 0)(!\goalwidth neg 0)
    \Label{16.5}
    \pcline[offset=9pt]{<->}(!\bredde 2 sub 0)(!\bredde 2 sub 16.5)
    \Label{16.5}
    \pcline{<->}(0,0)(0,11)
    \Label{11}
    \pcline[offset=-6pt]{<->}(!\goalwidth 5.5 add neg 0)(!\goalwidth 5.5 add neg 5.5)
    \ncput*{\tiny{\SI{5.5}{\m}}}
    \pcline[offset=6pt]{|<->}(!\goalwidth 0)(!\goalwidth 5.5 add 0)
    \ncput*{\tiny{\SI{5.5}{\m}}}
    \pcline[offset=-7pt]{|<->|}(!\goalwidth neg -2)(!\goalwidth -2)
    \Label{\Goalwidth}
    \rput(0,11){%
      \pcline{<->}(0,0)(9.15;60)
      \Label{9.15}
    }
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is _absolutely_ the same way to simply it as shown in your other example!

Comment: @Herbert Okay. I'll see what I can get done and post it if I find some 'smart' way of doing it.

Comment: @Herbert I have tried to simplify the code. I'm wondering if I can make you have a look at it at some point?

Comment: It will be more convenient if you provide the important values to construct so we don't need to calculate them.

Comment: @Bugbusters All the important values are on the output above. (`45` and `90` are variables.) I'm not exactly sure what you mean but it might be easier to see from the first code try I gave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not use `siunitx` it is overkill for writing only a length. `\scriptsize` and friends have no argument. The `{..}` have no meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

% Paremeters
\def\Laengde{90 }    \def\laengde{\Laengde 2 div }
\def\Bredde{45 }     \def\bredde{\Bredde 2 div }
\def\Goalwidth{7.32 }\def\goalwidth{\Goalwidth 2 div }
\def\halffield{%
  \psline(!\goalwidth neg 0)(!\goalwidth neg 2)%
         (!\goalwidth 2)(!\goalwidth 0)
  \psline(!\goalwidth neg 5.5 sub 0)(!\goalwidth neg 5.5 sub -5.5)%
         (!\goalwidth 5.5 add -5.5)(!\goalwidth 5.5 add 0)
  \psline(!\goalwidth neg 16.5 sub 0)(!\goalwidth neg 16.5 sub -16.5)%
         (!\goalwidth 16.5 add -16.5)(!\goalwidth 16.5 add 0)%
 \rput(0,-11){\psdot(0,0)\psarcn(0,0){9.15}{-37}{-143}}
}

\psset{unit=1.8mm,dimen=middel,nrot=:U,dotsize=3pt 2}
\begin{pspicture}(-25,-50)(25,50)
\psframe(!\bredde neg \laengde neg)(!\bredde \laengde)
\psdot(0,0)\psline(!\bredde neg 0)(!\bredde 0)\pscircle(0,0){9.15}
\rput(!0 \laengde){\halffield}
\rput{180}(!0 \laengde neg){\halffield}
\pcline[offset=9pt]{|<->|}(!\bredde neg \laengde neg)(!\bredde neg \laengde)
\ncput*{\scriptsize\Laengde m}
\pcline{<->}(!\bredde neg \laengde 3 div neg)(!\bredde \laengde 3 div neg)
\ncput*{\scriptsize\Bredde m}
\rput(!0 \laengde neg){%
  \pcline[offset=9pt]{<->}(!\bredde 2 sub 0)(!\bredde 2 sub 16.5)
  \ncput*{\scriptsize16.5 m}
  \pcline{<->}(0,0)(0,11)\ncput*{\scriptsize11 m}
  \rput(0,11){\pcline{<->}(0,0)(9.15;60)\ncput*{\scriptsize9.15 m}}
  \pcline{<->}(-7,0)(-7,5.5)\ncput*{\tiny5.5 m}
  \pcline[offset=6pt]{|<->}(!\goalwidth 0)(!\goalwidth 5.5 add 0)
  \ncput*{\tiny5.5 m}
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Question to Herbert from Svend Tveskæg: Can I use

```
\def\halffield{%
  \psframe(!\goalwidth neg 0)(!\goalwidth 2)
  \psframe(!\goalwidth neg 5.5 sub 0)(!\goalwidth 5.5 add -5.5)
  \psframe(!\goalwidth neg 16.5 sub 0)(!\goalwidth 16.5 add -16.5)
  \rput(0,-11){\psdot(0,0)\psarcn(0,0){9.15}{-37}{-143}}
}
```

instead of

```
\def\halffield{%
  \psline(!\goalwidth neg 0)(!\goalwidth neg 2)%
         (!\goalwidth 2)(!\goalwidth 0)
  \psline(!\goalwidth neg 5.5 sub 0)(!\goalwidth neg 5.5 sub -5.5)%
         (!\goalwidth 5.5 add -5.5)(!\goalwidth 5.5 add 0)
  \psline(!\goalwidth neg 16.5 sub 0)(!\goalwidth neg 16.5 sub -16.5)%
         (!\goalwidth 16.5 add -16.5)(!\goalwidth 16.5 add 0)
 \rput(0,-11){\psdot(0,0)\psarcn(0,0){9.15}{-37}{-143}}
}
```

?

Comment: Great, @Herbert! Good point about `{..}`.

Comment: I edited the code a bit. Forgot to define `\Goalwidth->\goalwidth`. Makes life easier ...

Comment: Nice. Thank you for simplifying it even further.

Comment: `dimen=middel`?

Comment: yes, works also, and I leave it as a competition to you why? ... :-)

Comment: It should be analogous to `showgrid=bottmo`.

Comment: @Herbert I have added a question to your code at the bottom of your post. please feel free to delete it.

Comment: sure, it is _nearly_ the same

Answer (score 1):

With `dimen=medusa`!

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,siunitx}

\psset{dimen=medusa,unit=3mm}

\def\Upper{%
    \psframe(-22.5,0)(22.5,45)% main rectangle
    \qdisk(0,0){3pt}% dot at center
    \psarc(0,0){9.15}{0}{180}% semi circle at center
    \psframe(-20.16,28.5)(20.16,45)% second rectangle
    \qdisk(0,34){3pt}% dot inside second rectangle
    \psarcn(0,34){9.15}{-37}{-143}% arc
    \psframe(-9.16,39.5)(9.16,45)% third rectangle
    \psframe(-3.66,45)(3.66,47)% fourth rectangle
}

\def\Label#1{\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\small\SI{#1}{\cm}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-24.5,-49)(23,47.5)
    \Upper\psscalebox{1 -1}{\Upper}
    \psset{arrows=|<*->|*}
    \pcline(-22.5,-15)(22.5,-15)\Label{45}% width
    \rput(0,-34){\pcline{<->}(0,0)(9.15;60)\Label{9.15}}
    \psset{offset=-1}
    \pcline(-20.16,-45)(-3.66,-45)\Label{16.5}
    \pcline(-3.66,-47)(3.66,-47)\Label{7.32}
    \pcline(-9.16,-45)(-9.16,-39.5)\Label{5.5}
    \psset{offset=1}
    \pcline(-22.5,-45)(-22.5,45)\Label{90}% length
    \pcline(3.66,-45)(9.16,-45)\Label{5.5}
    \pcline(0,-45)(0,-34)\Label{11}
    \pcline(20.16,-45)(20.16,-28.5)\Label{16.5} 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```